# How not to download/upload IMAP messages that already exist?

Tags: php, email, imap

I have a script with a loop that downloads messages from one server and uploads them to another.
I'd like not to waste a call on `imap_fetchbody` and `imap_append` if the message already exists in the target.
Is there something I can use in "message_not_existing_in_target"?

```
$source_imap = imap_open(...);
$target_imap = imap_open(...);
...
if (message_not_existing_in_target) {
    $message = imap_fetchbody($source_imap, $i, '', FT_PEEK);
    imap_append($target_imap, $mbox, $message);
}
```

At the very least I need:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($source_imap, $i, '', FT_PEEK);
if (message_not_existing_in_target)
    imap_append($target_imap, $mbox, $message);
```

As uploading tends to be slower than downloading.

I'd like to mention some IMAP services like Gmail's seem to have their own internal duplication check - they just return TRUE without actually saving the duplicated message. But the message needs to be uploaded in order to be detected as a duplicate, so it's still not efficient.

Comment: How do you define duplicate? Is there an internal unique id that is preserved during your copy operation?

Comment: Start from the lowest UID, and track (and save) the highest UID you've successfully sent to the other server.  Make sure you're always using UIDs (use the _UID flags to the various functions) and not message sequence numbers.

Comment: @CaiusJard - since these are different servers, I guess duplicate means identical headers+body (or just identical headers?).

Comment: @Max - I don't like to rely on a third server for "offline" tracking.

Comment: @LWC You have some options then: if your server supports arbitrary flags, you can set flags on the source and search for messages without that flag (I'm not sure the PHP library supports arbitrary flags).  You can keep a pseudo message somewhere with your state (using imap_append and imap_delete).  You can move processed messages to another folder on the source as well as copying them to the destination; you can delete the source message; all of these don't require you to download them.  You could abandon using IMAP to retrieve and put something in the SMTP path as a filter...

Comment: @LWC did my solution work?

Comment: Please see my comment to you there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sourceImap = imap_open('...');
$targetImap = imap_open('...');

$sourceMessages = $targetMessages = array();

$checkSourceImap = imap_check($sourceImap);
$checkTargetImap = imap_check($targetImap);

if (
    $checkSourceImap !== false &&
    $checkTargetImap !== false
) {
    $sourceImapOverview = imap_fetch_overview($checkSourceImap, "1:{$checkSourceImap->Nmsgs}");
    $targetImapOverview = imap_fetch_overview($checkTargetImap, "1:{$checkTargetImap->Nmsgs}");

    foreach ($sourceImapOverview as $sourceMessage) {
        $sourceMessages[$sourceMessage->msgno] = strtolower(urlencode($sourceMessage->subject) . '_' . urlencode($sourceMessage->from) . '_' . urlencode($sourceMessage->to)) . '_' . $sourceMessage->udate;
    }

    foreach ($targetImapOverview as $targetMessage) {
        $targetMessages[$targetMessage->msgno] = strtolower(urlencode($targetMessage->subject) . '_' . urlencode($targetMessage->from) . '_' . urlencode($targetMessage->to)) . '_' . $targetMessage->udate;
    }

    $newMessages = array_diff($sourceMessages, $targetMessages);

    if (!empty($newMessages)) {
        foreach ($newMessages as $messageNumber => $newMessage) {
            $message = imap_fetchbody($sourceImap, $messageNumber, '', FT_PEEK);
            imap_append($targetImap, $checkTargetImap->Mailbox, $message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If they are different servers, the UID will not be consistent, because the UID is assigned by the server.

Comment: Similar to what @Max wrote, isn't imap_mail_move meant for working on different folders in the same server?

Comment: I changed the answer to use imap_append with a custom unique identifier.

Comment: But what is this identifier? You just wrote `[...]`.

Comment: You may be able to create a custom unique identifier with a combination of return values from imap_fetch_overview.

I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: I see you've compared subjects, but that's not unique enough. In each e-mail each message will have "Re: this subject" and your solution will deduce they all moved together. You also use strtolower which assumes subjects of different cases are just one message. Read my comment to @CaiusJard above.

Comment: It combines the subject, from email, to email and udate string to form a unique string that also avoids exact duplicates.